# Set picturebox image to none vb

Tags: vb.net, image

I was wondering how to set a picture box to have no image and cannot seem to find that anywhere.

```
If GPU.SelectedItem = "None" Then
        GPUCost.Text = "$0"
        GCost = 0
        'Set this to No Image
        GPUImage.Image =
        '
        FullCost.Text = "Total Cost: $" & DCost + GCost + CCost + PCost
    End If

    If GPU.SelectedItem = "{GPU}" Then
        GPUCost.Text = "$45"
        GCost = 45
        GPUImage.Image = My.Resources.GPU_1
        FullCost.Text = "Total Cost: $" & DCost + GCost + CCost + PCost
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GPUImage.Image = Nothing
```

That's basically the null value in VB.NET.